# MOSFET instead of a contactor in Battery Management Systems (BMS)

Tags: mosfet, lithium-ion, contactor, bms

For relatively high current systems (>50 A) with Lithium based batteries, I've seen that usually BMS controls the output with contactors for both main supply and precharge. Why not use a high current rating MOSFET(s) to do this instead?

Comment: Cheap chinese BMSes do use MOSFETs. Perhaps the possibility of their failing short circuit doesn't matter for those applications and that market.

Comment: Thanks Brian. Failing short circuit like you said and also isolation of the high light current path from the BMS control circuit are two reasons that I have figured out. Anything else?